# how to configure the path of xampp in phpeclipse in linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, xampp

Hey, I have installed the phpeclipse plugin for eclipse under linux and I have xampp for my php, apache, etc. However, in order to configure eclipse correctly so that it can work with the xampp server, I need to point out the actual file names when configuring. But the way to start and stop xampp from the terminal is that "./xampp start or ./xammp stop and there are no actual files named like this, only a file named xampp. How can I configure eclipse? the tutorials I found are about installations under windows and macs. Thank you

Comment: i think you have to supply the full pathname to the xampp binary, otherwise eclipse cant find it

Answer (score 0):

that is because in linux you use a lamp, it is configure just use you packagemanager,  or try google it something like

> lamp on debian
>   http://www.google.com.mx/search?sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=lamp+on+debian

as you can see they are a lot of tutorial's about anything distro